# Now that we're in holiday travel season, help promote Travel Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

We're entering a season of many harvest, beginning-of-winter/calendar turnover, and religious/commercial holidays.

Millions of people will be traveling to spend these holidays with friends, family, or sharers of faith, and they'll have lots of questions. Travel Stack Exchange has a great opportunity to expand its canon of travel knowledge and provide the best answers to those questions.

AND it's a great time to recruit new members!

What can you do to help?

1. As you plan and go on holiday trips, whenever you have questions, ask them here. You're not the only one having that
   question. Millions of other people will, too. Ask them even if you
   think you're going to be able to find the answer yourself... and if
   you do find the answer, go ahead and answer it yourself.
2. When answering holiday questions, do everything you can to overkill it.
   Don't just answer with a hyperlink to some other discussion group
   somewhere. Write a detailed, step-by-step, ultra-clear guide with references, screenshots or photos (if applicable) and examples. Help us have the best possible answer to the common problems and questions people have with traveling during the holidays.
3. If a question comes in that is unclear, badly written, badly
   formatted, or in bad English, edit it into shape. We've always
   encouraged edits that improve spelling, grammar, and clarity. Make
   every question into a full sentence.

This is a great opportunity to build up a body of answers to common travel questions that will be super-popular in the coming weeks as hordes of people plan trips. Those questions will bring in lots of traffic from search engines and if Travel Stack Exchange continues to have great answers like we have in the past, we stand a chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come.

*Note: Shamelessly stolen and adapted from [Joel's successful promotion](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589/10998) to build new content for Apple SE.*

Comment: So true.  Especially number 2.  More facts and details included also equals more words that might just get picked up by search engines.  It's scary what words have brought people to my blog over the years ;)